# Streamlining appending of boolean column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

**Disclaimer: My code is very amateurish as I am still undergoing course work activities. Please bear with me if my code is inefficient or of poor quality.**

I have been learning the power of pandas in a recent Python tutorial and have been applying this to some of my course work. We have learnt how to use boolean filtering on Pandas so I decided to go one step further and try to append boolean values to a column in my data (efficiency).

The tutor has said we should focus on minimising code as much as we can - 
I have attempted to do so for the below efficiency column.
The baseline efficiency value is 0.4805 (48.05%). If the values are above this, it is acceptable. If it is below this, it is a 'fail'.

I have appended this to my dataframe using the below code:

```
df['Classification'] = (df[['Efficiency_%']].sum(axis=1) > 0.4805)
df['Classification'] = (df['Classification'] == True).astype(int)
```

While this is only 2 lines of code - is there a way I can streamline this further into just one line?

I had considered using a 'lambda' function which I am currently reading into. I am interested if there are any other alternatives I could consider.

My approaches I have tried have been:

1. For Loops - Advised against using this due to it being inefficient.
2. If statements - I couldn't get this to work as I can't append a '1' or '0' to the df['Classification'] column as it is a dataframe and not a series.

   ```
   if i > 0.4805:
   df['Classification'].append('0') else:
   df['Classification'].append('1')if test
   ```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the same; It's unnecessary to sum a one column data frame by row, `df[['Efficiency_%']].sum(axis=1)` is the same as `df['Efficiency_%']`, and also *Boolean Series == True* is not necessary as it yields the same result as Boolean Series itself.

```
df['Classification'] = (df['Efficiency_%'] > 0.4805).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is far simpler than I thought. If you don't mind - would you be able to elaborate on the 'IF' statement part of my question? Is it actually possible to append values to a dataframe via the IF approach?

Comment: You can't append a scalar value to a Series, If you want to take the for loop approach, create a list, append `0` and `1` to the list and then assign the list as a column to the data frame: Something like `lst = []; for i in df['Efficiency_%']: if i > 0.4805: lst.append(1) else: lst.append(0); df['Classification'] = lst`.

Comment: Thank you very much Psidom! I will write this down in my notes as that is a very useful approach.